# Not able to get req.body in NextJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, axios

I am trying to access req.body in my API. But I am not able to get and in console I checked the  request tab there is the string I want.

[image: Request Tab]

and here is another image

[image: Response Tab].

Below is my code

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === "DELETE") {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
    if (!session) {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ message: "Please sign in" })
    }

    // Validate ID
    const postId = req.body
    console.log(postId)
    if (!postId) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "Post ID is missing", body: postId })
    }

    // Delete Post
    try {
      const result = await prisma.post.delete({
        where: {
          id: postId,
        }
      })
      res.status(200).json(result)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Error has occured while deleting the post", body: postId})
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to get the postId using req.body.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found that instead of `req.method === "DELETE"` I should have use `req.method === "POST"`. So, I don't know the reason behind this but it is a solution. Feel free to post the reason for it. If anyone know.

Comment: If you are sending the data to the server from a `form`, there may be issues, because `PUT` and `DELETE` are not supported by definition, so only `GET` and `POST` may work:


https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms

Try to make a call with data as query string instead as request body.